# CSS @page rule: How to preview in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, printing

IE seems to be the only web browser supporting page margin boxes (see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms530841(v=vs.85).aspx)). I have tested my CSS with WeasyPrint and it seems to be working fine. My question is: How do I actually see the @page rule being applied in IE? I currently use IE11. I can see the @media print rule being applied on Print Preview, however, the @page rule doesn't seem to be applied (and I am not nesting the @page rule inside the @media print rule). Can somebody please shed some light onto how the print preview with applied @page rule can be initiated?

Here is how my page rule looks like:

```
@page {

size: A4 portrait;
margin: 1.5cm 1.5cm 1.5cm 1.5cm; 

@top-left-corner {
    content: ""; /* has to be specified! */
    background-color: rgba(42, 201, 80, 0.220);
    border-bottom: solid green; 
}

@top-left {
    width: 70%;
    content: "";
    background: url('images/logo_v4.png'), rgba(42, 201, 80, 0.220);
    background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat;
    background-position: left center, left;
    background-size: contain; /* 5cm, cover or 100%: scale bg image, retains img ratio */ 
    border-bottom: solid green;
} 

@top-right {
    width: 30%;
    content: "Page " counter(page) " of " counter(pages);
    vertical-align: middle; 
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 0.7cm;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #53c963;
    border-bottom: solid green;
    }

@top-right-corner { 
    content: " "; 
    background-color: rgba(42, 201, 80, 0.220);
    /* background-color: #79caff; */
    border-bottom: solid green; 
}

@bottom-center {
    width: 100%;
    content: "Reporting Powered by Open Source Software";
    vertical-align: middle; 
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 0.7cm;
    color: green;
}
```

}

Comment: IE has been replaced by Edge.  @page rule seems to be working there.

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript, the cssRules collection contains the CSS rules of a style sheet, and the CSSPageRule object represents a @page rule. The cssRules collection does not contain the @page rules in Firefox and Safari before version 5, and it is not supported in Internet Explorer before version 9. If you want to get the @page rules in older Internet Explorer versions, use the pages collection. There is no way to access to a @page rule in Firefox and in older versions of Safari.

```
   <head>
    <style id="myStyle">
        @page :first {
            margin-left: 13cm;
            margin-right: 4cm;
        }
    </style> 

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function GetPageRule () {
            var styleTag = document.getElementById ("myStyle");

                // the style sheet in the style tag
            var sheet = styleTag.sheet ? styleTag.sheet : styleTag.styleSheet;

            if (sheet.cssRules) { // all browsers, except IE before version 9
                    // the page rules are not in the cssRules collection
                    // in Firefox and Safari before version 5
                if (sheet.cssRules.length > 0) {
                    var pageRule = sheet.cssRules[0];
                    alert (pageRule.cssText);
                    return;
                }
            }
            else {  // Internet Explorer before version 9
                if (sheet.pages) {
                    var pageRule = sheet.pages[0];
                    alert (pageRule.selector + ":" + pageRule.pseudoClass);
                    return;
                }
            }

                // Firefox, Safari before version 5
            alert ("Your browser does not support this example!");
        }
    </script> 
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="GetPageRule ()">Get the page rule!</button>
</body>
```

Comment: This is interesting, thanks, however it doesn't answer my question. I added above my page rule.